# Swift 4: specify file path, or move file location

Tags: swift, xcode, file, path, filepath

I have some code which records audio and then plays it back. The file saves as .m4a file, and is buried deep in library/developer/etc etc

I would like to save instead to the desktop, or at least to be able to move the file to a selected path. I'm new to Swift, and this has foiled me unfortunately!

Here is what I currently have for file path. I'm sure only minor changes are needed, but I'm not at all sure how.

Any help very much appreciated!

```
// Path for saving/retrieving the audio file
func getAudioFileUrl() -> URL {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in:     .userDomainMask)
    let docsDirect = paths[0]
    let audioUrl = docsDirect.appendingPathComponent("recording.m4a")
    print(audioUrl)
    return audioUrl
}
```

Comment: Try this method ` FileManager.default.moveItem(at: URL, to: URL) `.

Comment: "this has foiled me unfortunately!"  What does that mean?